# How to define globaly the suffix of external data files

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I use `multiplot` in order to plot simultaneously several external data files. The names of all these data files have the same prefix and also have the same structure, hh_data1.out, hh_data2.out, etc. The prefix "hh" is the variable. So, I am wandering if there is a way to declare it only once, probably before entering multpiplot mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sprintf` function to format you file name:

```
var = 'hh'
tmpl = var.'_data%d.out'
plot sprintf(tmpl, 1)
```

You may also consider to iterate through the datafiles for plotting:

```
do for [i=1:3] {
    plot sprintf(tmpl, i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I was aware of the do loop.